# Image circle cropping in imagemagick

Tags: image, command-line, imagemagick, crop

People, I am using imagemagick to crop a circle out of an image. But I am getting nothing when I run this command :

```
convert input.jpg +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 539,539 539,0" -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite output_circ.jpg
```

I am getting an output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKUN.jpg):

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 6):

Fundamentally, you are only missing one aspect - JPEG files cannot store transparency, so you need to use a PNG or GIF, for example.

```
convert input.jpg -alpha on \( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 539,539 539,0" \) -compose copy_opacity -composite output_circ.png
```